# Permanent sessions using Codeigniter db sessions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

**application/config/config.php**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Since I have a permanent sessions: `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` and the session updates every 5 minutes: `$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;` there are huge number of unused rows in the **ci_sessions Table**. **In a day for just 3 to 4 users the ci_sessions table data went to 1 mb**

So, I wanted to do something like:

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 60*60*24*365*2;
and
var $gc_probability = 0;
```

2 years of expiry time and update time, so for a single browser there will be only 1 entry in the ci_sessions table which will never be deleted, since the gc probability is 0. And I will have my own clean up code to remove unused sessions every month or so. But the problem is:

> Its not just the session update which makes a new entry into the
>   ci_sessions table, but every refresh makes a new entry. which will
>   create the same problem of having huge no.of unused sessions.

How to avoid new session id per every refresh or a page call?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because if the session expiration is set to 0 then it isn't actually being treated as unlimited. It is just never saving the session. How about setting the expiration to one year?

I don't see the need to keep sessions this long as they will be removed when the user closes their browser (I see you have the browser setting off, its still a possibility if the user has their cookies cleared on browser close) or clears their cookies manually. It is also a security risk if you are dealing with logins etc..

You say you are using a database but a snippet of your code begs to differ?

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
```

Try having the session expiry time higher than the session update time, this might be causing the issue. Have you tried increasing the expiry time to say 60 seconds and refresh the page a couple of times?

Comment: `sess_use_database = false` was a typo. But, if the session expiration is set to 0 it takes it as 2 years(in the source code).`I don't see the need to keep sessions this long as they will be removed when the user closes their browser (I see you have the browser setting off, its still a possibility if the user has their cookies cleared on browser close) ` This doesn't happen, if I set `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;`. But, yes it happens when the cookies are cleared, which is a expected behavior

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Try having the session expiry time higher than the session update time, this might be causing the issue. Have you tried increasing the expiry time to say 60 seconds and refresh the page a couple of times?

Comment: `if ($this->sess_expiration == 0)
  {
   $this->sess_expiration = (60*60*24*365*2);
  }` this is what i found in the Session class. So, 0 is actually 2 years.